# Calculating the quality of text parsing script

Tags: text-mining, measurement-error, agreement-statistics, cohens-kappa

I have a python script that picks relevant sentences from a text corpus based on keywords and stopwords and applies some classifiers for the chosen sentences. The context is academic research.

The text corpus is not a "sample" in the statistical sense but more akin to a "full population." That is, it has every document produced by the investigated institution from the analyzed period.

Is there an established way to estimate the errors produced by the flaws in my script? Here, the measure of quality is how close it would be to a human doing the picking and classifying.

I was thinking about picking a small random sample, analyzing it manually, and calculating Cohen's kappa between the human results and the script output. Any better ideas?